# Migrating from then/catch promises chain to async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to convert a chain of promises .then().catch to async/await functions

```
const chain = [
    {
        onFulfilled: () => {/*some logic*/},
        onRejected: () => {/*some logic*/},
    {
        onFulfilled: () => {/*some logic*/},
        onRejected: () => {/*some logic*/},
    {
        onFulfilled: () => {/*some logic*/},
        onRejected: () => {/*some logic*/},
    },
    //...
];
const data = 'initial data';
let promise = Promise.resolve(data);
let i = 0;
while (i < chain.length) {
    promise = promise.then(chain[i].onFulfilled).catch(chain[i].onRejected);
    i++;
}
```

The final promise is equal to:

```
promise = Promise.resolve()
.then(chain[0].onFulfilled).catch(chain[0].onRejected)
.then(chain[1].onFulfilled).catch(chain[1].onRejected)
.then(chain[2].onFulfilled).catch(chain[2].onRejected)
....
```

Here is what I've tried so far

```
let data = 'initial data';
for (const fn of chain) {
  try {
      data = await fn.onFulfilled(data);
  } catch (e) {
      data = await fn.onRejected(e);
  }
}
```

The prolem is: if fn.onRejected throw an error, the error causes for loop to stop rather than handled by the next fn.onRejected

Comment: Nothing prevents you to put a nested `try / catch` within your `catch` block. In this way, if `fn.onRejected` throws something you can just log an error and go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code. Messy but works

```
let data = 'initial data', unhandledError;

for (const fn of chain) {
  if(unhandledError) {
    try {
      data = await fn.onRejected(unhandledError);
      unhandledError = null;
    } catch (e) {
      unhandledError = e;
    }
    continue;
  }

  try {
      data = await fn.onFulfilled(data);
      unhandledError = null;
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      data = await fn.onRejected(e);
      unhandledError = null;
    } catch (e) {
      unhandledError = e;
    }
  }

if(unhandledError) throw unhandledError;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify that `while` mess with a `for..of` loop -

```js
let p = Promise.resolve(initialData)
for (const {onFulfilled, onRejected} of chain)
  p = p.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)
```

Which is the same as -

```js
const p = chain.reduce(
  (acc, {onFulfilled, onRejected}) =>
    acc.then(onFulfilled, onRejected),
  Promise.resolve(initialData)
)
```

I don't think you gain anything by using `async..await` for this. As you already pointed out, it introduces more complexity due to `try..catch`.